# How to get Glob() working again after upgrading from Google Cloud App Engine PHP 5.5 to 7.3?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

After upgrading from the App Engine PHP 5.5 runtime to 7.3, [Glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) no longer works to sort trough our Cloud Storage files.

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
$bucket = $storage->bucket("MyBucketName");
```

I have enabled the StreamWrapper and all other file operations work fine (scandir, opendir, unlink, reading files etc.)
No longer being able to use `glob()` is a deal breaker as sorting trough our Cloud Storage  is now too slow and creates timeouts. Using the Cloud Storage prefixes is not viable on the current naming and really inflexible.

```
$allLogFiles = glob($fileSystemLogFolder."*_".$_REQUEST['DeleteVersionNrLogs']."_*",GLOB_NOSORT); //No longer works
$allLogFiles = scandir($fileSystemLogFolder, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE );//Does work
```

Is it possible to get `glob()` working for PHP 7.3 App Engine + Cloud Storage API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, seems that is not possible Mike. You can achieve your goal by using a custom runtime in the Flexible environment, or a VM with PHP 7.3.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/